# SELinux: Why do common utilities need to be compiled with custom flags

Tags: selinux

See: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SELinux#SELinux_aware_system_utilities

Why are they compiled with SELinux? If they aren't, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, the Arch repos tends to attempt to avoid patching upstream packages.  Instead preferring to work with upstream to fix problems.

But in some cases, there are standards that need to be implemented for the package to work best with the rest of the distribution.

Your list contains [iproute2-selinux](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/iproute2-selinux).  It appears to use the same sources as [iproute2](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/iproute2-selinux), but adds a single [patch](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/0001-make-iproute2-fhs-compliant.patch?h=iproute2-selinux).  This patch fixes FHS (file system heirarchy) compliancy. In the original iproute, data is stored in the LIBDIR.  After applying the patch, data is stored in DATADIR (`/usr/share`).

In another example [dbus-selinux](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/dbus-selinux) is simply `dbus`, but adds an [install hook](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/dbus-reload.hook?h=dbus-selinux) which causes dbus to reload its configuration after a package upgrade. It also adds a small [patch](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/no-fatal-warnings.diff?h=dbus-selinux) which changes the behaviour of fatal warnings.

[`coreutils-selinux`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/coreutils-selinux) is another example.  It uses upstream sources directly, and then builds with `--with-selinux` and adds a dependency to its own `libselinux`.

If we look in the upstream sources of coreutils (git://git.sv.gnu.org/coreutils), we see several runtime switches that use `is_selinux_enabled()`.  These have low-level comments like "attempt to preserve the SELinux security context", "Change SELinux context of file", and "it requires an SELinux-enabled kernel".  It looks like the code is taking advantage of extra security features offered by a patched kernel.

Comment: How is this related to SELinux though? And, say, for example, the coreutils-selinux package. It adds the --with-selinux flag. What does that do?